# How to margin top and left the leading Icon flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

Am having trouble regarding margin-left and top on the Apppbar, am using the `leading` icon, but I failed to reposition it.

Below is my code :

```
child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
              child: AppBar(
                leading: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                height: 200,

                child: Transform.scale(scale: 2,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/app_logo.png')
                  ,
                ),
                )
                ),
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/path.png'))
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorColor: Colors.lime,

                tabs:[
                  Tab(icon: null,text: 'RECENT',),
                  Tab(icon: null, text: 'TOPICS',),
                  Tab(icon: null, text: 'AUTHORS',),
                ]
            ),
          )
```

This is where my styling for the `leading` icon is :

```
leading: SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    height: 200,

                    child: Transform.scale(scale: 2,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Image.asset('assets/app_logo.png')
                      ,
                    )
```

This is screen shot :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can easily change the size of the leading widget regarding the [layout of the AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

But you can use a `Stack` widget to put your logo over the AppBar like this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorColor: Colors.lime,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    icon: null,
                    text: 'RECENT',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: null,
                    text: 'TOPICS',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: null,
                    text: 'AUTHORS',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 60),
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Center(child: Text('Logo')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your amazing approach, it has worked like charm